# Need my points back

Tags: discussion, review-queues

I made my own answer at one place - [What is the difference between JDK and JRE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906445/what-is-the-difference-between-jdk-and-jre/24660677?noredirect=1#comment38268204_24660677)
and copied it to another - [Java SE 6 vs. JRE 1.6 vs. JDK 1.6 - What do these mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/250517/java-se-6-vs-jre-1-6-vs-jdk-1-6-what-do-these-mean/24681126?noredirect=1#comment38268210_24681126)
Both answers were deleted citing plagiarism. I want one answer (first one) to be un-deleted. My answer adds useful info to the question, instead of just citing random differences between jdk and jre. I need those points back. Please do the needful.

Thanks.

Comment: No. Plagiarism isn't copying stuff from yourself. It is copying it from **other people** (in particular without attribution).

Comment: You didn't make your own answer.. you copied it from somewhere else. At least copy the important pieces, link to it and make your own answer out of that. Either through paraphrasing or fair use.

Comment: Worth reading: [Users are calling me a plagiarist. What do I do?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160077/users-are-calling-me-a-plagiarist-what-do-i-do)

Comment: Andrew Barber did leave you a message on those posts. You could have mentioned that...

Comment: You really should consider a new title to this question. It really makes you sound upset over internet points.

Comment: @SterlingArcher - I need 50 to be able to comment. Thats why i am upset.

Comment: So earn them? It's very easy to get those back without copying a blog post to get them. Earn your reputation the right way bro

Comment: @SterlingArcher - I added a citation. Does that solve this mess ?

Comment: In the time you spent complaining about this, you could have answered another question and gotten upvotes. Think about it.

Comment: Note that 'Please do the needful' is not correct English, *and* it comes over as extremely demanding. It sounds like you are saying [*sudo give me my points back*](http://xkcd.com/149/). Interaction with a community does not work that way. You catch more flies with honey than you do with vinegar!

Comment: @MartijnPieters http://xkcd.com/357/

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**Both** answers were plagiarised, with the majority of your answer copied verbatim from [this blog post](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/02/07/how-debuggers-work-part-3-debugging-information/).

Don't copy and paste someone else's work and claim it as your own. That's both plagiarism and a copyright violation; you did not credit the real author making the text look like it was your own, and posts on Stack Overflow are licensed under the CC license with is usually incompatible with the license of the original work, so copying someone else's work verbatim is something you can only do when you have permission from the copyright holder.

*Citing* a blog post is fine, but you need to use only extracts, and link to the original source. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing for more information on how to cite someone's work correctly. A more detailed FAQ on plagiarism is also available: [Users are calling me a plagiarist. What do I do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160077/users-are-calling-me-a-plagiarist-what-do-i-do)

Comment: I think I learned that in Kindergarten :/

Comment: I really really want to post a verbatim copy of this answer.

Comment: But I added a valuable point. Okay, I'll add a citation for the info for debugging information.

Comment: Plagiarism and copyright violation are not the same thing - I would be careful not to use those terms interchangeably.

Comment: @Steve: Don't just put a citation since it still implies what you wrote is your own words. Make sure you put everything that is copied word-for-word into a block quote, *along* with linking to the source.

Comment: @AirThomas Is the fact that your comment appears to omit the word "omited" intentional or unintentional irony?

Comment: my info - To debug into Java system classes such as String and ArrayList, you need a special version of the JRE which is compiled with "debug information". The JRE included inside the JDK provides this info, but the regular JRE does not. Regular JRE does not include this info to ensure better performance.

Comment: @Servy: I believe AirThomas was referencing [this meme](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/i-accidentally)

Comment: @BoltClock: Yes, I was being too imprecise there.

Comment: I cant add a new answer. old one cannot be undeleted. That question is going to lose a valuable point. Is there a way to get it back ?

Comment: @MartijnPieters - I added a citiation. Can you please undelete the answer now ?

Comment: @Steve: You got those points because you had unfairly taken credit for someone else's work, which the users upvoting you didn't know. Users can get suspended over (repeated) plagiarism; it shows some chutzpah to complain about internet points when you're caught. Anyway, you *can* edit your deleted answer. Once you've fixed it you can flag and ask a moderator to undelete it (other users cannot), though whether they do or not is up to them.

Comment: @DavidRobinson - But I added a valuable point and used the blog to explain one term in my explanation. Here is my point - To debug into Java system classes such as String and ArrayList, you need a special version of the JRE which is compiled with "debug information". The JRE included inside the JDK provides this info, but the regular JRE does not. Regular JRE does not include this info to ensure better performance.

Comment: @Steve: That doesn't change the fact that the rest of your answer was not your own writing. When you quote something that you did not write, you must cite the source - no exceptions.

Comment: @BoltClock - I added a citation now. Can u pls undelete ?

Comment: @Steve: Edit the post to fit the guidelines I linked you to, then flag the post for moderator attention, and *ask nicely*. It was deleted by a moderator, and can therefor only be undeleted by a moderator.

Comment: @Steve: Even in your edited answer you did not take my advice to put the copied text in a blockquote. I've edited your deleted answer to demonstrate. You *really* should read [this link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160077/users-are-calling-me-a-plagiarist-what-do-i-do) (particularly the section on **How do I properly add attribution in the future?**), since if you infringe again (accidentally or intentionally) you could get suspended, which is a good deal worse than losing a few points.